# Ubuntu 18.04 crashes randomly while using Unity

Tags: unity, 18.04, crash

two days ago I switched from 16.04 to 18.04. I did a complete reinstallation. I installed unity via

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

As display manager I'm using 'lightdm'.

Now I'm facing the problem that Ubuntu crashes randomly while using the Unity Desktop. First the side bar and the menu bar are disappearing and then 2 seconds later the login screen opens where I have to enter my password again. The problem does not occur if I use gnome.

Things I already tried:

- Deinstalling unity tweak tool, because I guessed that this packages somehow overlaps with the new tweak tool which is already included in the plain installation

What could I do next to fix this behaviour?

Comment: Try solutions from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but the error is still there

Comment: Haven't heard many users having success with doing this. These desktops are vastly different and since canonical is only investing in gnome desktop, I'd recommend using one or the other. Currently there's little to no evidence that unity will ever be made to play nice with ubuntu ever again.